# Power Series Questions

Tags: power-series

I'm confused on how to solve these types of questions when it comes to Power Series.

The question states:
For the following differential equations, give guaranteed convergence intervals for the expansion of the solutions in powers of x.

Question 1:

```
y''[x] - y[x] = Sin[x] 
y[0] = 3
y'[0] = -1
```

Question 2:

```
(1 - x) y''[x] - y[x] = Sin[x]
y[0] = 3
y'[0] = -1
```

I understand how convergence intervals work and can use the Ratio test or Power Series Convergence Test when I actually see the expansions of the functions, but I'm having difficulty when the question is formed like the examples above.

Comment: Please add what your thoughts are about the question. As it stands the question doesn't fit the rules described in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, then $y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}$ and $y''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$. Thus,

$$y''(x)-y'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[(n+1)(a_{n+1}+(n+2)a_{n+2})\right]x^n$$

Now equate the quantity between square brackets to each of the coefficients of the power series expansion of $\sin(x)$.